# Find the eigenvectors of a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvectors of this matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

It's easy to see that all eigenvalues for this matrix are 1, with multiplicity 4. But the only eigenvector I can find is $(1, 0, 0, 0)^*$. How do I find the other three?

Comment: In fact, there is only one eigenvector up to scalar multiple.

Comment: $A-I$ has rank 3 so there is just 1 eigenvector. There is a notion of generalized eigenvectors however. Look up the Jordan form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix in question. Indeed, $\lambda=1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ as you say. Row reducing $\lambda I_4-A$ to find the kernel (from which we find the eigenvectors), we have:
$$\begin{align}\lambda I_4-A&=I_4-A\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1-1&0-2&0&0\\0&1-1&0-2&0\\0&0&1-1&0-2\\0&0&0&1-1\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}0&-2&0&0\\0&0&-2&0\\0&0&0&-2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\&\to \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{multiplying the first three rows by $-\frac{1}{2}$}\end{align}$$
Hence, $\lambda I_4-A$ has rank $3$ and thus nullity $1$. So there is only one linearly independent eigenvector for $\lambda=1$.